# Flutter web compiled package method throws a typeError but doesn't in development

Tags: flutter

Our app runs fine on web when running locally in deveopment but the moment we run release we get an error from one of our packages:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gh8')`

I've verified that the type is running correctly in dev and in the fork of the package I'm running. Is there any reseason the compiler would not be aligning the types or methods of a package we're using? The type before compiling is a CameraOptions class for the Mapbox package.

I've tried running locally, forking the report to add debuggin within it to verify it's getting the correct objects, making sure it's formatting and recieving types correctly. In development everything works as expected. I've also ensured that all of our packages are web compatible. Does anyone know why the compiled version would be failing but not throwing the error when running in dedug mode?